# Laravel belongsToMany relationship with only one result

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a relationship between two tables with a join table that only has one result.

When I define a Laravel belongsToMany relationship, instead of returning a collection with only one element I would like to have it return that item alone.

Is there a way to model this in Laravel?

Thanks in advance.

[**EDIT**]

I'll try to explain what I want using the classic Users/Roles example. Besides de `users` and `roles` tables, we'll have a `users_roles` pivot table which will store all the roles the user has had. A user can, at any given time, have only one active role (identified by the `active` attribute being `true`).

```php
class User {
    function role() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivot('active', 'true');
    }
}
```

With this relationship definition, when I access `$user->role` I get a collection (with only one element) of Roles. What I would like is to have that Role instance directly.

Comment: show us some code that what you acheive so far

Comment: Please show tables data and Models Laravel codes

Comment: Does your pivot table have additional attributes (besides the foreign keys)?

Answer (score 14):

In my case that was the most straight forward solution:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function services()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Service::class, 'service_user')
                    ->using(ServiceUser::class)
                    ->withPivot('user_id', 'service_id', 'is_main_service');
    }

    public function mainService()
    {
 
        return $this->hasOneThrough(Service::class, ServiceUser::class, 'user_id', 'id', 'id', 'service_id')
                    ->where('is_main_service', 1);
    }
}
```

Pivot table class:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class ServiceUser extends Pivot
{
    
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in Laravel 9, but I had to ensure the pivot table had an incrementing id and the pivot table class had the `public $incrementing = true;` property.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know why you have belongsToMany if you need only one relation, however below code will help you:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product');
}

public function specific_product()
{
    return $this->products()
                ->where('column','value')->first();
}
```

OR

```
public function getSpecificProductAttribute()
{
    return $this->products()
                ->where('column','value')->first();
}
```

Comment: I have several entries in the pivot table but only one is valid and that is the one I want to return. I like your approach.

Comment: The "problem" with this solution is that I cannot access it as a property, like normal relationships...

Comment: then change specific_product to getSpecificProduct then you can get directly form parent model

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue, and have found a really clean way to solve it.

First, change the name of the accessor function that returns the `belongsToMany` result to reflect the fact that these return multiple results. In your case this would mean using `roles` instead of `role`:

```
function roles() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role')->wherePivot('active', 'true');
}
```

Then add the following to your model:

```
protected $appends = ['role'];

public function getRoleAttribute() {
  return $this->roles()->first();
}
```

Now, when you call `$user->role` you'll get the first item.

Comment: This solution will make performance bad (queries in loop) on handling multiple records of user.

Comment: @ThanhDao - OK - didn't realise that. What is your proposed solution? Could you post it?

Comment: not sure if its the best solution, but in my case the performance is not important. cause its in a small range of records. and this one works

Answer (score 2):

I faced the exactly same issue, let me show you how I managed it.

In my case a have a belongsToMany relationship between materials and customer_types, the pivot table contains the material price for specific customer types, therefore there are as many records (prices) in the pivot table as customer_types are.

**What I expected:** when a price is requested for a specific customer_type I want to get the scoped price for that specific customer_type **as a nested element**.

**What I got:** a collection with only 1 element.

This is what I had at the beginning in my Model:

```
class Material extends Model
{
    public function customer_types(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\CustomerType', 'customertype_material', 'material_id', 'customertype_id')->withPivot('price');
    }
}
```

Of course, when I requested the customer_types for a specific customer_type the result wasn't the expected one:

```
$resources = Material::with(['customer_types' => function($query) use ($customer_type_id){
                        $query->where('customertype_id', $customer_type_id);
                       }])->get();
```

It was returning a Material model with a customer_types nested collection with 1 element on it, forcing me to use first() or loop over 1 element.

**The solution:** Create a Model that extends the pivot table and add a relationship to it.

Created a new model that extends the pivot:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot;

class CustomertypeMaterial extends Pivot
{
    protected $table    = 'customertype_material';
    protected $fillable = ['price', 'customertype_id', 'material_id'];
}
```

Now, added a relationship pointing to this new model in my Material Model:

```
public function scoped_price(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\CustomertypeMaterial', 'id','material_id');
}
```

Finally the query loading this new relationship:

```
$resources = Material::with(['scoped_price' => function($query) use ($customer_type_id){
                        $query->where('customertype_id', $customer_type_id);
                       }])->get();
```

The result is a Material model with a scoped_price element nested on it and filtered by a customer_type_id

I'm not sure if it's the right way to do this, but it's working for me.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have written a more generic approach to solving this issue. The downside to it is that I had to copy code from the laravel/frame vendor files. So this might break someday when upgrading Laravel Framework.

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Arrayable;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

/**
 * Based on laravel/framework@8.54.0
 */
trait SupportsSingleResultBelongsToMany
{
    /**
     * Get the model's relationships in array form.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function relationsToArray()
    {
        $attributes = [];

        foreach ($this->getArrayableRelations() as $key => $value) {
            // If the values implements the Arrayable interface we can just call this
            // toArray method on the instances which will convert both models and
            // collections to their proper array form and we'll set the values.
            if ($value instanceof Arrayable) {
                if (isset($this->forceSingleResult) &&
                    in_array($key, $this->forceSingleResult) &&
                    $value instanceof \ArrayAccess &&
                    $value instanceof \Countable
                ) {
                    $relation = count($value) > 0 ? $value[0] : null;
                } else {
                    $relation = $value->toArray();
                }
            }

            // If the value is null, we'll still go ahead and set it in this list of
            // attributes since null is used to represent empty relationships if
            // if it a has one or belongs to type relationships on the models.
            elseif (is_null($value)) {
                $relation = $value;
            }

            // If the relationships snake-casing is enabled, we will snake case this
            // key so that the relation attribute is snake cased in this returned
            // array to the developers, making this consistent with attributes.
            if (static::$snakeAttributes) {
                $key = Str::snake($key);
            }

            // If the relation value has been set, we will set it on this attributes
            // list for returning. If it was not arrayable or null, we'll not set
            // the value on the array because it is some type of invalid value.
            if (isset($relation) || is_null($value)) {
                $attributes[$key] = $relation;
            }

            unset($relation);
        }

        return $attributes;
    }
}
```

Then in your model, just use the Trait and specify which relations are single result.

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use SupportsSingleResultBelongsToMany;

    protected $forceSingleResult = ["teams"];

    public function teams()
    {
        $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Laravel Eloquent works on the principle of magic. You can override the magic method `__get`.  If there is no property, the `__get` method is called:

(in your model)

```
    public function __get ($name)
    {
        $answer = parent::__get($name);
        if($name=='your_prop'){
            $answer=!empty($answer)?$answer[0]:null;
        }
        return $answer;
    }
```

If your `your_prop` to-many relationship returns anything take the first in the array.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain this answer some?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php
Laravel Eloquent works on the principle of magic.
If there is no property, the __get method is called